# Update People picker value using javascript

Tags: javascript, people-picker, updatelistitems

My function is :

```
function UpdatePerform() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListOnboarding);

        var item = oList.getItemById($("#idC").val());

        var Superior = $("#Superior").val();
        var Employees = $("#SuperEmployeesior").val();

        item.set_item('ImmediateSuperior', Superior);
        item.set_item('EmployeesReportingToThisUser', Employees);

    item.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded_SaveTo), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed_SaveTo));
}
```

When i want to update the person field, it empty it!
can anyone help me please?

Comment: I guess the `.val()` method of jQuery returns a string. You need to probably use the `EnsureUser`-method on this string (if it's for example `domain\user`) and cast the result to `New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue`

Comment: Steff i used this to update the single selection in the People Picker : var Superior = $("#Superior").getUserInfo(); and when i debug i can see the value of Superior 0: "i:0#.f|membership|seriesk@test.com" But finally i get Unknown Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
function UpdatePerform() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ListOnboarding);

var item = oList.getItemById($("#idC").val());

var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.Employees_TopSpan;
// Get information about Employees
var Employees = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();

var Users = new Array();
if (Employees != 0) {

    for (var i = 0; i < Employees.length; i++) {
        var arryuser = Employees[i];
        Employ = arryuser["DisplayText"];
        Users.push(SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(Employ));
    }
} else Users = null;

 item.set_item('EmployeesReportingToThisUser', Users);

item.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded_SaveTo), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed_SaveTo));
 }
```